Azure ACS: CreateCall works but CallMedia Play is unauthorized
I am following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/tutorials/postman-tutorial
Using this same code, I called https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/create-call/create-call?view=rest-communication-callautomation-2023-10-15&tabs=HTTP and it works perfectly.
Next step, I called https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/call-media/play?view=rest-communication-callautomation-2023-10-15&tabs=HTTP with the callConnectionId I obtained from the previous API call.. and I keep getting
{
    "error": {
        "code": "7509",
        "message": "HMAC-SHA256 validation failed"
    }
}

My body for CallMedia-> play is
{
  "playSources": [
    {
      "kind": "text",
      "text": {"voiceKind": "male", "text": "Hello. This is Microsoft calling. If you are trying to authenticate, please press the pound or hash key now", "sourceLocale" : "en-US"}
    }
  ],
  "playTo": [
    {
        "phoneNumber": {
            "value": "+11231230672"
        }
    }
   ]
}

Where am I going wrong?
I tried changing
pm.request.headers.upsert({
    key:'Authorization',
    value: "HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=" + signature
});

to
pm.request.headers.upsert({ key:'Authorization', value: "HMAC-SHA256 Credential=" + pm.variables.get("credential") + "&SignedHeaders=x-ms-date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=" + signature });
But that leads to an "invalid header parameter"
I tried hardcoding endpoint, url .. but no luck.
Can you please help?

The issue with HMAC-SHA256 validation when trying to make a call to the Azure Communication Services (ACS) API for playing media during a call due to invalid key details.
The following are steps to CallMedia play:

Create and configure a Postman collection
Add the pre-request script from this link

// Set the Date header to our Date as a UTC String.
const dateStr = new Date().toUTCString();
pm.request.headers.upsert({key:'Date', value: dateStr});

// Hash the request body using SHA256 and encode it as Base64
const hashedBodyStr = CryptoJS.SHA256(pm.request.body.raw).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
// And add that to the header x-ms-content-sha256
pm.request.headers.upsert({
    key:'x-ms-content-sha256',
    value: hashedBodyStr
});

// Get our previously specified endpoint variable
const endpoint = pm.variables.get('endpoint')
// Remove the https, prefix to create a suitable "Host" value
const hostStr = endpoint.replace('https://','');

// This gets the part of our URL that is after the endpoint, for example in https://contoso.communication.azure.com/sms, it will get '/sms'
const url = pm.request.url.toString().replace('{{endpoint}}','');

// Construct our string which we'll sign, using various previously created values.
const stringToSign = pm.request.method + '\n' + url + '\n' + dateStr + ';' + hostStr + ';' + hashedBodyStr;

// Decode our access key from previously created variables, into bytes from base64.
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(pm.variables.get('key'));
// Sign our previously calculated string with HMAC 256 and our key. Convert it to Base64.
const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

// Add our final signature in Base64 to the authorization header of the request.
pm.request.headers.upsert({
    key:'Authorization',
    value: "HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=" + signature
});


Connect the Cognitive Services to the Communication Service

Add collection variables for Call Setup and create two variables:

key - This variable should be one of your keys from your Azure Communication Services' key page within the Azure portal. For example,  oW...A==.

endpoint - This variable should be your Azure Communication Services' endpoint from the key page.  Ensure you remove the trailing slash. For example,  https://contoso.communication.azure.com.



Call Setup with Cognitive Services:
POST https://contoso.communications.azure.com/calling/callConnections?api-version=2023-10-15
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

{
  "callbackUri": "https://app.contoso.com/callback",
  "targets": [
    {
      "kind": "phoneNumber",
      "phoneNumber": {
        "value": "+919"
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceCallerIdNumber": {
    "value": "+183"
  },
  "sourceDisplayName": "Contoso Support",
  "callIntelligenceOptions": {
    "cognitiveServicesEndpoint": "https://<your-cognitive-service-endpoint>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
  }
}


Play Call with Text-to-Speech:
POST https://contoso.communications.azure.com/calling/callConnections/{callConnectionId}:play?api-version=2023-10-15
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

{
  "playSources": [
    {
      "kind": "text",
      "text": {
        "voiceKind": "male",
        "text": "Hello. This is Microsoft calling. If you are trying to authenticate, please press the pound or hash key now",
        "sourceLocale": "en-US"
      }
    }
  ],
  "playTo": [
    {
      "kind": "phoneNumber",
      "phoneNumber": {
        "value": "+919"
      }
    }
  ],
  "playOptions": {
    "loop": true
  },
  "operationCallbackUri": "https://app.contoso.com/callback"
}

Output:


Thanks Sampath. With your code above, I was able to get rid of the issue of HMAC failure. "kind": "phoneNumber", was missing in my payload. However, now that HMAC is not an issue, the call works and I do get a 202 back.. but I cannot hear any voice being played on the call. I tried Play and Recognize.. both.. same issue.. I get a success response, but no voice being played.

i  think there is problem with text format. please try with {   "playSources": [     {       "kind": "file",       "playSourceCacheId": "string",       "file": {         "uri": "https://some.file.azure.com/sample.wav"       }     }   ],  . upload the sample mav file to azure blob stroage and use sas url of the blob in the url.

The final solution was this
Postman pre-request script
    // Set the Date header to our Date as a UTC String.
    const dateStr = new Date().toUTCString();
    pm.request.headers.upsert({key:'x-ms-date', value: dateStr});
    
    // Hash the request body using SHA256 and encode it as Base64
    const hashedBodyStr = CryptoJS.SHA256(pm.request.body.raw).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
    // And add that to the header x-ms-content-sha256
    pm.request.headers.upsert({
       key:'x-ms-content-sha256',
       value: hashedBodyStr
    });
    
    // Get our previously specified endpoint variable
    const endpoint = pm.variables.get('endpoint')
    // Remove the https, prefix to create a suitable "Host" value
    const hostStr = endpoint.replace('https://','');
    
    // This gets the part of our URL that is after the endpoint, for example in https://contoso.communication.azure.com/sms, it will get '/sms'
    //const url = pm.request.url.toString().replace('{{endpoint}}','');
    var url = pm.variables.replaceIn(pm.request.url.toString());
    // console.log('url here ', url)
    // console.log('endpoint ', endpoint);
    url = url.replace(endpoint,'');
    
    console.log('url final', url)
    
    // Construct our string which we'll sign, using various previously created values.
    const stringToSign = pm.request.method + '\n' + url + '\n' + dateStr + ';' + hostStr + ';' + hashedBodyStr;
    //console.log('stringToSign', stringToSign)
    // Decode our access key from previously created variables, into bytes from base64.
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(pm.variables.get('key'));
    //console.log('stringToSign', stringToSign)
    // Sign our previously calculated string with HMAC 256 and our key. Convert it to Base64.
    const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    
    // Add our final signature in Base64 to the authorization header of the request.
    pm.request.headers.upsert({
       key:'Authorization',
       value: "HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=x-ms-date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=" + signature
    });

Call request post-response script
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    // Stores the callConnectionId in an environment or global variable
    var callConnectionId = responseJson.callConnectionId;
    pm.environment.set("callConnectionId", callConnectionId);

Call request body
    {
     "callbackUri": "https://sub.domain.com/v0/CallBack/Add",
     "sourceCallerIdNumber": {
       "value": "+18441231234"
     },
     "targets": [
       {
         "phoneNumber": {
           "value": "+11231231234"
         }
       }
     ],
     "callIntelligenceOptions": {"cognitiveServicesEndpoint" : "https://yourresource.cognitiveservices.azure.com"}
    }

Recognize API call
Has headers added for Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key = 
User-Agent : Something Voice OTP
Body
    {
       "recognizeInputType": "dtmf",
       "playPrompt": {
           "kind": "file",
           "file": {
               "uri": "https://some-url/some-voice-otp.wav"
           }
       },
       "recognizeOptions": {
           "interruptPrompt": true,
           "initialSilenceTimeoutInSeconds": 5,
           "targetParticipant": {
                   "kind": "phoneNumber",
                   "phoneNumber": {
                       "value": "+11231231234"
                   }
               },
           "dtmfOptions": {
               "interToneTimeoutInSeconds": 35,
               "maxTonesToCollect": 1,
               "stopTones": [
                   "asterisk"
               ]
           }
       }
    }

RETRY Recognize API call
Has headers added for Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key = 
User-Agent : some Voice OTP
Body
    {
       "recognizeInputType": "dtmf",
       "playPrompt": {
           "kind": "file",
           "file": {
               "uri": "https://some-url/some-voice-otp-tryagain.wav"
           }
       },
       "recognizeOptions": {
           "interruptPrompt": true,
           "initialSilenceTimeoutInSeconds": 5,
           "targetParticipant": {
                   "kind": "phoneNumber",
                   "phoneNumber": {
                       "value": "+11231231234"
                   }
               },
           "dtmfOptions": {
               "interToneTimeoutInSeconds": 35,
               "maxTonesToCollect": 1,
               "stopTones": [
                   "asterisk"
               ]
           }
       }
    }

DECLINE auth API call
Has headers added for Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key = 
User-Agent : Some Voice OTP
Body
    {
     "playSources": [
       {
         "kind": "file",
         "file": {
           "uri": "https://some-url/some-voice-otp-declined.wav"
         }
       }
     ],
     "playTo": [
       {
           "kind": "phoneNumber",
           "phoneNumber": {
               "value": "+1231231234"
           }
       }    
      ],
     "operationCallbackUri": "https://some-url.com/v0/CallBack/Add"
    }

Terminate auth API call
Has headers added for Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key = 
User-Agent : BHPS Voice OTP
Body
None
